# Eclipse C++ multiple main error only when using multiple headers

Tags: c++, eclipse, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to learn how to utilize header files in C++ projects, so I made .cpp files containing simple functions to make sure I'm doing all the declaring and including correctly.
Everything worked fine when I only had one set of .cpp and .h files, but when I try to add more I get errors.

To start with, in my project I had:

helloworld.cpp

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int HelloWorld() {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

helloworld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H_INCLUDED
#define HELLOWORLD_H_INCLUDED
int HelloWorld();
#endif /* HELLOWORLD_H_INCLUDED */
```

main.cpp

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

Which built with no errors and ran correctly.

Next I tried adding a second .cpp and .h file, which created building errors.

pointers.cpp

```
#include "pointers.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Pointers() {
    int x = 1;
    int *ptr_a = &x;
    cout << *ptr_a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

pointers.h

```
#ifndef POINTERS_H_INCLUDED
#ifndef POINTERS_H_INCLUDED
int Pointers();
#endif /* POINTERS_H_INCLUDED */
```

and modified main.cpp:

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include "pointers.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    HelloWorld();
    Pointers();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I try to build, I get an error saying there are multiple definitions of main -- one in main.cpp, and the other in pointers.cpp.

Even more oddly, if I make a new project and do the exact same thing but reverse the order in which I create the .cpp and .h files (i.e. pointers first then helloworld), it builds and runs correctly with just the pointers files but runs into the same error when adding helloworld files, saying that the multiple exceptions of main are in main.cpp and helloworld.cpp.

I figure it must have something to do with Eclipse itself, but I don't know what the exact issue is.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: *I get errors.* Recommend adding these so we can help you through them. Switch to the build console, if you're not using it already, and get them from the build output. They're easier to copy and paste as well as more complete.

Comment: Instead of making `pointers()` return an int you should change it to `void Pointers()` and get rid of the `return 0;` Same goes for `HelloWorld()`

Comment: Is your build configuration using the Eclipse internal builder, make with Eclipse generated makefiles, or your own makefile?

Comment: Typo: pointers.h has `#ifndef POINTERS_H_INCLUDED` and `#ifndef POINTERS_H_INCLUDED` The second one should be `#define POINTERS_H_INCLUDED`. Just dropped the code into eclipse, made the change and I'm not getting any more errors. Output looks like what I'd expect, so I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: That should be an answer I feel @user4581301

Comment: @Hemil It's just a cut and paste mistake. Everybody does them and the solution is simply the impossible "Don't do that." No one's going to learn anything useful from a formal answer. This is exactly what the  Off-topic: non-reproducible or typographical error close-vote is for.